# When to create new solr core?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

Do applications that utilize solr typically create a single core, or should one create a new core to handle each search function for unrelated data.

For example, I have an application with user search, document search, client search, and workflow search.  Would one typically create four cores to support this, or simply load all the data into a single core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you search for. If your document search is completely separate from user search and you never search across both of those types - make them separate. But if you search across users and documents and clients with one query - make them same.